Deflated file is larger than original and still valid
Inside a zip, I found this deflated file. It's around 1MB, but when inflated (pako.inflateRaw), the original is just 50kb. How is this possible? What happens to the rest of the data when inflated? I've tried to figure out what's going on by building something to see the rest of the file, but most of it is garbage and I couldn't find where the actual content is.
Link to file: https://github.com/KTibow/hoster/raw/main/file.deflate

Can you provide a link to the zip file you pulled this from?

@MarkAdler it's actually a .jar, the relevant file is the second META-INF/MANIFEST.mf here's a link: https://github.com/KTibow/hoster/raw/main/NotEnoughUpdates-2.1.1-Alpha-27.jar

What do you mean "second"? There is only one in there, it is the first file, and is not your file.deflate data. That META-INF/MANIFEST.mf entry is 205 bytes long and decompressed to 282 bytes.

If you look at it in a hex editor, there are two file declarations, but the first one is the only one referred to in the central directory. (edit: I think that this manifest might actually be for a zip that was embedded inside the zip, not sure though)

"Not sure though"?? Then how exactly did you extract file.deflate?

There are four .jar files in the jar file. All of their manifest files are also on the order of 100 to 200 bytes. None of them correspond in any way to the initial deflation of your file.deflate.

I did a naive approach to extracting because the jar doesn't contain "compressed size" data, where I read until I saw another signature. This was my first approach, and it probably ended up reading data that doesn't mean what I thought it meant. That's how I got file.deflate, from the bytes 0x000269F6-0x00108D83.

I missed one. There are five jar files in your .jar. Your extract is from the middle of neu-mixin-libraries-wrapped/mixin-0.7.11-SNAPSHOT.jar, which is itself deflate compressed. You'd need to inflate it before you can get inflatable deflate data from inside it.

You need to post a new question with what exactly you are trying to do. Whatever it is that you're trying to do, that's definitely not how to do it.

Deflate streams are self-terminating. The deflate stream at the start of that file is 17,400 bytes, and decompresses to 49,424 bytes. Then inflate stops.
